# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded while comparing two excel files

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I get **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded** exception while comparing two excel sheets like this

```
   public void compareExcels(String primaryKey, String path1, String path2, String OutPath) throws Exception{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataSheet1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataSheet2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ExcelUtilities obj = new ExcelUtilities();      
    /*Read both the worksheets in ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> objects */
    /*Apache POI api is used for reading excel data*/
    dataSheet1 = obj.readExcel(path1);
    dataSheet2 = obj.readExcel(path2);
    /* pk holds the key column name using which comparison should be done*/
    ArrayList<String> pk = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(primaryKey.split(";")));
    /* compare method takes care of comparing the two ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> objects and returns a map with row number and match result */
    HashMap<Integer, String> result = obj.compare(dataSheet1,dataSheet2,pk);    
    /* Mismatch excel report is created*/
    obj.writeToExcel(result, OutPath+"result.xlsx");
 }
```

The above code is working absolutely fine with few thousands of excel records. But when size of the input sheets increases to, say 50k records in each excel sheet, program is running into **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded**

I understand -

1. *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError* is thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the garbage collector
2. I'm trying to read huge volumes of data into two `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` objects which could be the root cause of this issue
3. To solve this, one option is to increase heap size mentioning the Heap size I want to extend as

   - Xmx - max heap size

But this is not an elegant solution. I may need this program to compare two excel sheets with one million records each. I want to implement an efficient algorithm with right data structures. Need your thoughts on this.

Comment: Is `ExcelUtilities` a class you have written?  I do not see it in the POI documentation.  In general, it appears you are attempting to read the entire Excel document into memory and the only way to reduce that is to figure out how to read chunks of the file in and compare the chunks but not the whole file at once.  The exact solution will depend on what the Excel file is to figure out how to chunk it.

Comment: Yes. `ExcelUtilities` is the class I have written, which has methods to read, write to excel. Apache POI is used for implementing these methods.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think anyone will be able to answer the question as asked because it is too specific to the code you have written and too broad to narrow down to a specific change you can implement.  Like above if you want to fix this you will have to work out a strategy where you do not load the entire file into memory while operating on it.